# Hibernate - Join Table with Composite ID

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, composite-id

I have a Person Table (`PersonID`), and an Address table (`AddressID`). I want to create a new Join table called `Person_Address` which maps `Person->Adress` using a `ManyToMany` relationship and I have to specify the primary key as a composition of the two primary keys (`PersonID - AddressID`).

How can I do that using Hibernate HBM syntax?

Comment: This link might be helpful to you - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/manual/en-US/html/components.html#components-compositeid

Answer (score 1):

Use `@ManyToMany` and forget about join tables in Hibernate. The join table will exist in your database, but not in your code, Hibernate knows how to handle this.

Example:

Person class (as the owner of the relationship):

```
@ManyToMany(targetEntity = Address.class, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, fetch = fetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "person_address", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PersonID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "AddressID"))
List<Address> addresses;
```

Address class (if it's required):

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, mappedBy = "addresses", targetEntity = Person.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
List<Person> persons;
```

Edit:

This [link](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example/) will help you with the many-to-many XML mapping.

Comment: Thank's for the answer, its just that i'm not using Annorations ... i have to specify that in an HBM file that's why i'm looking for the syntax

Comment: Ok, let me try to provide and example with XML :)

Comment: I've added a link with an example in XML. Wow, it's very long in XML ;)

Comment: @user1948363, it was useful to you? If so, accept the answer :)